# Barplot in a loop

Tags: r

I have such data:

```
groups = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

var1 = c(2,3,4,4,6,8)

dat = data.frame(groups, var1)
```

For each value in `groups` I want to plot a histogram of `var1`. So, I expect 3 histograms with 2 entries of `var1`.

I tried it by a loop:

```
for (i in unique(dat$groups)) {
  hist(dat$var1)
}
```

However, it plots all entries of var1 but not just the values which occur together with each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going by the loop approach, you need to manually subset the data

```
hist(subset(dat, groups == i)$var1)
```

Or else, you can use ggplot2 for the purpose which has better functionality and provides better look and feel. I can simply give you the code, but if you are new to R, I will suggest you spend some time with basics of ggplot. Or else the code will simply look like magic

Comment: Yes; I could do: `library(ggplot2) library(dplyr) dat %>%  filter(groups == 1) %>%   ggplot(aes(x = var1)) + geom_histogram()` ...but thats too much code.

Comment: See ```facet_wrap()``` and ```facet_grid()``` with ggplot. The dplyr part is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to `split` the data by `groups` and `lapply` function `hist` to each sub-dataframe.

```
subdf_list <- split(dat, dat$groups)
h_list <- lapply(subdf_list, function(DF) {
  x11()
  hist(DF[['var1']])
})
```